# ExchangeFilterFunction executing code outside WebClient reactive flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm creating `ExchangeFilterFunction` for extended logging during `WebClient` requests.

Question: is there any difference if I execute the logging inside the `.doOnNext()` function in the following example? Or are they equal in processing?

```
ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
    LOGGER.info("Request url=" + clientResponse.url() + ", method=" + clientResponse.method());
    return Mono.just(clientRequest);
});

ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
    return Mono.just(clientRequest).doOnNext(clientResponse2 -> {
        LOGGER.info("Request url=" + clientResponse2.url() + ", method=" + clientResponse2.method());
    });
});
```

Is there any advantage for one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

I just loath any artificial introduction of `Mono.just` or similar into your flow. I suppose that `.doOnNext` is one extra step but I cannot imagine it makes any difference whatsoever. Better to avoid breaking the flow up. I think that would be your worst performance penalty.

Note: This will log when `WebClient` is invoked, as noted below, and generally looks a little uglier than using the convenience methods, but it avoids using `Mono.just`.

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
            .filter(eff)
            .build();
    webClient.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).subscribe(System.out::println);
}

ExchangeFilterFunction eff = (cr,ef)->{
    System.out.println("method: " + cr.method());
    return ef.exchange(cr)
    .map(cresp->{
        System.out.println(cresp.rawStatusCode());
        return cresp;
    });
};
```

Comment: But adding the logging explicit as step into the webclient call is what I'm trying to avoid. I'd rather configure the webclient one time with the global logger, and then on any webcall do not have to care about the logging, as it is applied automatically. Similar to how `RestTemplate`s are configured with interceptors for logging.

Comment: What is it you think your code was doing? Read further down in the baeldung article and you will see many other possibilities. Then there are still other possibilities as well.

Comment: There actually is a difference, please see my answer.

Comment: That's nice and all, but off topic. I don't think the webclient would be called at all if it wasn't subscribed to.

Comment: You'd be wrong. 

It may well be INVOKED in a .switchIfEmpty() but never subscribed to because the other publisher emits a value. I do this all the time.

The entire point was you don't (and shouldn't) know how the publisher is used. You need to do things on subscription, not invocation.

Comment: I get you but I don't think that's the point of a WebClient logger. I'd want to see what actually happened during invocation.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case the webclient will invoke the filter correctly. However, be careful about this in general.

In the first case the logging will happen when the method is **invoked**.  It could actually be incorrect if the caller never subscribes to the returned publisher. The publisher could also be called many times like in the case of a retry or repeat, etc. and that will be wrong too.

In the second case it will be called every time it is **subscribed** to.

```
public class Foo {

    static Mono<String> echo(String message) {
        System.out.println("echo called with " + message);
        return Mono.just(message);
    }

    static Mono<String> rxEcho(String message) {
        return Mono.just(message).doOnNext(msg -> System.out.println("rxEcho was called with " + msg));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //logged, even though never actually called
        echo("no sub");
        //only logs 1 time
        echo("retry")
            .repeat(3)
            .blockLast();

        System.out.println("---------------");

        //never subbed, never logged
        rxEcho("no sub");

        //all 4 calls are logged
        rxEcho("retry")
            .repeat(3)
            .blockLast();
    }
}
```

Also note you shouldn't call any flavor of block() in real code, I didn't want to confuse the example with StepVerifier.